# Joomla 2.5 core override

Tags: joomla2.5

In an attempt to override Joomla core files I have created a plugin. The code is as follows:

```
    jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin');

    class plgSystemComContentOverride extends JPlugin {

  public function __construct(&$subject, $config = array()) {
     parent::__construct($subject, $config);
 }

 public function onAfterRoute() {
     $app = JFactory::getApplication();
     if('com_content' == JRequest::getCMD('option') && !$app->isAdmin()) {
         require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'comcontentoverride' . DS . 'my_content_controller.php');
     }
 }
```

}

Can anyone see why this isn't working or offer some debugging tips? I can't even conclude that onAfterRoute() is being accessed.

Comment: I think I had a similar issue and it was because I had made the plugin a content plugin instead of a system plugin. What does your xml file look like?

Comment: <extension version="2.5" type="plugin" group="system">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a naming convention problem. This seems to be a recurring theme for me! It seems completely undocumented in Joomla. As far as I can tell it needs to be:
plg[Type of plugin][name of php file] in camel case, to complicate it. So in my instance it would be:

```
    class plgSystemCustomclassloader extends JPlugin
```

The files in the folder being customclassloader.xml and customclassloader.php